# Create a virtual device appear an error "The skin directory does not point to a valid skin"

Tags: android, sdk, android-virtual-device, skin

My SDK tools to version 24.2
and SDK with Android 4.4W.2 (API 20).

I used Android Virtual Device (AVD) to simulate Android wear devices.
but appear error "The skin directory does not point to a valid skin"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you choose skin? Do like my captures, It works. Firstly, choose Android x86. Secondly, click ADVANCE SETTINGS to select CUSTOM SKIN DEFINITION.

[image][image]

Answer (score 52):

I just had to close the dialog window and try creating the emulator again

Answer (score 5):

I clicked on the `...` button and chose my `$ANDROID_SDK/skins` (`~/Library/Android/sdk/skins` on my mac) directory, and then I was able to choose the appropriate skin.

Comment: This was bizarre, happened to me on a fresh Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3 install after imaging a mac. I installed adoptopenjdk11 via brew from the AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk tap prior to the Android Studio install, and when Android Studio was doing initial install it asked what JDK to used, I pointed at openjdk. Perhaps that confused it? Either way, this was the path that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the case you create the device manually just by screen size, android studio might give you this error. Under advanced options you can explicitly select `no skin` to make the error go away.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error "The skin directory does not point to a valid skin." when creating an Android wear virtual device using AVD manager launched from Android Studio.

Solution for me was to pick the "Wear OS Round" skin option instead of the "Wear OS Round Chin" in previous screens.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The hardware file must be missing if you are getting this error. Make sure to add them by going to the previous page as shown in the attached image, click on *New Hardware Profile*, and click on *Next*.

Your problem should then be sorted.

[image: virtual device config]

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a face palm but in case it helps someone else.

I recently had this problem and it was because I didn't realize the skin I downloaded had two zip files inside of it for two different colored emulators. So, not only was I one level too high, Android Studio also didn't know what to do with those zip files.

Once I unzipped them and pointed to one, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers helped me.  I was UNable to find the correct directory because the Library is a hidden folder on Apple OS and for some reason Android Studio won't let me access hidden folders.  So I had to link the hidden directory inside of a visible  one:

1. Hidden folder: `/Users/user_name/Library/Android/sdk/skins/pixel_2`
2. I created a new UNhidden folder called: `/Users/user_name/development/skin`

The code I used to link it is:
`ln -s /Users/timothy_brinkley/Library/Android/sdk/skins/pixel_2 skin`

[Screenshot of what the new shortcut looks like in the Finder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVISO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I used the option new device and I choose one skin then it's working.

[image]