# android studio is stuck at "Loading device skin this can take few seconds" while creating AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

[As you can see in the image it's stuck at "Loading device skin this can take few seconds" i have waited 1 hr but it's not showing my virtual devices this is my first time using android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n5lq.png)

i haven't tried anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was low on storage

Answer (score 0):

I had this when I was trying the Cordova thing with terminal opened.
After I close my terminal, Android Studio will be able to add AVD.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend restarting android studio, to invalidate cashes or repair ide.

Compare this:
[Create a virtual device appear an error "The skin directory does not point to a valid skin"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251213/create-a-virtual-device-appear-an-error-the-skin-directory-does-not-point-to-a)